# Return default value if no results found in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently am using this query to select "profile_picture from the column relation and table media, although I noticed my return default.png inside my html image tag doesn't work for results. 
Is there any way I could return:
IF error

```html
"SELECT * FROM media WHERE post_id = '5552773e65a2b' AND relation = 'profile_picture"
```

My current query

```html
"SELECT * FROM media WHERE userID = $friend->user_id AND relation = 'profile_picture' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this would  probably be easier to handle with your scripting language, you could do a `union all` to get the default value since you're ordering by the `id` field:

```
SELECT id, picture 
FROM media 
WHERE userID = $friend->user_id 
    AND relation = 'profile_picture' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT -1 id, 'default.png' picture
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23f01/2)

Comment: I tried that although it didn't work, where the SELECT -1 id, part is, would -1 represent the first row in the table? 
I tried it and this is the output: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: @CassieJRound -- don't use `select *` -- when using `union`, you should explicitly define your columns.  In this example, I used id and picture...

Comment: Yep I also tried without *, here is my query:

`SELECT id, post_id, relation 
FROM media 
WHERE userID = 48 
    AND relation = 'profile_picture' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT -1 id, '5552773e65a2b' post_id
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: @CassieJRound -- when using `union`, both `select` statements must have the same number of columns.  Since you're selecting 3 fields in your first query, you need to select a third field in your second one.  In this case, `... union all select -1 id, '5552773e65a2b' post_id, 'profile picture' relation...`  With that said, you presumably need to return `default.png` somewhere to go with your example.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, just altered the query, and its all working now :)